# non profit edition Id?

Tags: org, nonprofit-starter-pack

Is there a way to determine from the OrgId if the Org is a non-profit edition? I'm hoping to use the OrgId that is provided in the License Management App to automate the non-profit discount for my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a truly distinct nonprofit edition. Salesforce grants free and discounted Enterprise Edition licenses to nonprofits.

You can look for the presence or absence of the Nonprofit Success Pack managed package, but it's installable whether or not one is receiving Salesforce.org's nonprofit license grant. Additionally, some nonprofits use NGO Connect or older NPO-specific customization layers, or none at all.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but I appreciate the info. Thanks David.

Comment: As a former nonprofit Salesforce developer, thanks for adopting Salesforce's discount/grant model. It does a lot of good for NPOs with limited resources.

Comment: Happy to do so. I was hoping to piggyback on Salesforce's determination of non-profit status, rather than having customers have to submit info to me.

Comment: You probably already know this, but in my experience, most vendors request a copy of the nonprofit's 501(c)(3) determination letter from the IRS. Every nonprofit has that document to hand because they need it all the time.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, US and Canada are easy -- it's the other ones that'll be tricky trying to figure out what to ask for.